# BinaryFormatter to send TCP message - Determine end of message

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, binaryformatter

I'm using the BinaryFormatter.Serialize method to send TCP messages.The class I am serializing is of the form:

```
[Serializable]
public class Message {
        public int senderId;
        public int metaData;
        public foo moreMetaData;
        public object[] message;
}
```

I know that, in general, there are three ways to determine the end of any message:

- Prepend size byte
- Append end of message bytes
- fixed message length

The third option seems like a terrible idea. If I use the second option, How can I append a byte to the stream and still be able to call BinaryFormatter.deserialize on the receiving end? If I use the first option (sorry for going through the list backwards), I have the same problem as option two (except with prepending), and I have the additional problem of determining the size of the serialization before I serialize, which seems to be impossible without serializing twice - once into a dummy variable to determine the size, and then again into the real stream buffer. What is generally done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryFormatter already implements "Prepend size byte" internally. You only need to pass in your `NetworkStream` object in to the [`BinaryFormatter.Deserialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx) method and it can figure out on its own how many bytes need to be read.

**NOTE:** BinaryFormatter is extreemly sensitive to version diffrences in assemblies. If you have one version of the program on one end and a slightly older version on the other your two ends may not be able to talk to each other. I would recommend using a binary serializer that does not tie the model to assembly version numbers. [ProtoBuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) is a good library to use instead.

**EDIT:** Here is a example of how you can do it

```
private async Task MessageLoop(NetworkStream networkStream)
{
    //Lets pretend our protocall sends a byte with:
    // - 1 if the next object will be a Foo,
    // - 2 if the next object will be a Bar
    // - 3 if the next object will be a Int32.

    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (true)
    {
        var read = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (read < 0)
        {
            await LogStreamDisconnectAsync();
        }

        switch (buffer[0])
        {
            case 1:
                //If we are on a SynchronizationContext run the deseralize function on a new thread because that call will block.
                Func<Foo> desearalize = ()=> (Foo)formatter.Deserialize(networkStream);
                Foo foo;
                if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
                {
                    foo = await Task.Run(desearalize).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    foo = desearalize();
                }

                await ProcessFooAsync(foo).ConfigureAwait(false);
                break;
            case 2:
                var bar = await Task.Run(() => (Bar)formatter.Deserialize(networkStream)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await ProcessBarAsync(bar).ConfigureAwait(false);
                break;
            case 3:

                //We have to loop on Read because we may not get 4 bytes back when we do the call, so we keep calling till we fill our buffer.
                var bytesRead = 0;
                while (bytesRead < 4)
                {
                    //We don't want to overwrite the buffer[0] so we can see the value in the debugger if we want, so we do 1 + bytesRead as the offset.
                    bytesRead += await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 1 + bytesRead, 4 - bytesRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                //This assumes both ends have the same value for BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
                int num = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 1);

                await DoSomethingWithANumberAsync(num).ConfigureAwait(false);

                return;
            default:
                await LogInvaidRequestTypeAsync(buffer[0]).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using 

    `byte[] buf = new byte[1024];   
    await networkStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);`

to read my message from the buffer. how do I determine when to call BinaryFormatter.deserialize?

Comment: @WreckFish you only read enough with ReadAsync to tell what the next message type will be, you then hand the stream off to the Desearalize function. I updated my answer with a example.

Comment: Thanks. It is becoming clearer. However I still have a few questions about the example. How does this determine when the rest of the data is received after `var read = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1).ConfigureAwait(false);`. I'm assuming this has to do with `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but I don't understand what these things are or do. Also, why are there so many async calls here? once the data is received, couldn't we afford to make calls like deserialize() and processFoo() synchronously?

Comment: If you are on the UI thread and the thing you are awaiting is complete before the call returns (for example if the data you are reading from `ReadAsync` is already in the OS's network buffer) the call never switches context so `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no affect on it. The reason I put so many async calls is because I wanted to have some functions process the data and I wanted to show those processes would not block the thread.

Comment: As for "when" the data is processed, it starts processing as soon as that first byte we read in becomes available, after that the `formatter.Deserialize(networkStream)` will block  till the NetworkStream has all the data transmitted, that is why we put it on a `Task.Run` if we are in a sync context, so we don't block the UI thread.

Comment: Ok got it. Deserialize works because it knows when to stop reading, so there is no issue of getting partial data. However we need to make it async because it may take time to get all of the data (Tell me if I completely misunderstood). Thanks!

Comment: You got it. That is what is going on.